# Problem with entity manager in Spring Webflux

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, entitymanager

In my web client, where I started using Spring WebFlux, I got following exception:

```
reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No EntityManager with actual transaction available for current thread - cannot reliably process 'persist' call
Caused by: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No EntityManager with actual transaction available for current thread - cannot reliably process 'persist' call
```

Code:

```
@Service
@Transactional
@Slf4j
public class PersonSyncServiceImpl
        extends HotelApiCommunicationService implements PersonSyncService {

    private static final String REST_ENDPOINT_PATH = "/api/sync/person";

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;
    @Autowired
    private SynchronizationService syncMgr;


    @Override
    public int initialSyncPersonData(ObiektDTO obiekt) {

        WebClient client = WebClient.create("http://" + obiekt.getAdresIp());
        AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);

        Flux<Person> personFlux = client.get()
                .uri(REST_ENDPOINT_PATH)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(Person.class);

        personFlux.subscribe(person -> {
            CNPerson cnPerson = syncMgr.convertObject(person, CNPerson.class);
            cnPerson.setObiektLoid(obiekt.getLoid());
            em.persist(cnPerson);
            count.getAndIncrement();
        });

        return count.get();
    }
}
```

I know that the problem is on this line, because reactor can't get entity manager.

```
em.persist(cnPerson);
```

Controller method on server:

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/person", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON_VALUE)
    public Flux<Person> getPersonList() {

        return Flux.fromStream(
                personDao.findAll().stream());
    }
```

How to fix it? How to access transaction with reactor and using JPA save a record to database?

Comment: You need to call a method on an external service which does the save, beware if you have 100 persons you also have 100 individual transactions!.

Comment: @M.Deinum Is it possible to do it in one transaction?

Comment: No, unless you are using Spring 5.2 and use the whole reactive stack, which doesn't work with JPA because that is using JDBC which is blocking. So without a fully reactive stack that isn't possible.

Comment: @M.Deinum: Is there other method to get a stream on client side and save every record to database in one transaction without Webflux?

Comment: You can use toIterable() method, it returns Iterable of your persons, but the method is blocking, but as I can see your method initialSyncPersonData return incorrect count, because subscribe works asynchronously.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, Spring Data R2DBC doesn't work with JPA/Hibernate and blocking JDBC Driver. So either, you need to get rid of webflux or JPA.

1. **With JPA**

If suppose, you decide to proceed with JPA, then you can call the Person Sync API using Spring [RestTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html) or WebClient Blocking call like this:

```
   List<Person> persons = client.get()
                .uri(REST_ENDPOINT_PATH)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(Person.class)
                .collectList()
                .block();
```

Transform them like you are doing;

```
List<CNPerson> cnPersons = new ArrayList();
persons.forEach(person -> {
  CNPerson cnPerson = syncMgr.convertObject(person, CNPerson.class);
  cnPerson.setObiektLoid(obiekt.getLoid());
  cnPersons.add(cnPerson);
});
```

And then save them all in one shot, using your `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository.saveAll()` [For this, you need to create a Repository for the `CNPerson` Entity.]

Or manually manage the transaction and save each `CNPerson` within it.

Lastly, to answer your question *Is there other method to get a stream on client side?*  - Answer is **NO** if you want to do it in one transaction. Coz you have to load the entire response of the Person Sync API in memory.

2. **Without JPA (Using Spring Webflux and R2DBC)**

You can still have transactional with Spring Data R2DBC. You can read more about it [here](https://spring.io/blog/2019/05/16/reactive-transactions-with-spring). Note that with R2DBC, you have to use the Non-blocking drivers for whatever type of database you are using. A list is given [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/r2dbc/docs/1.1.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#r2dbc.drivers).

Answer (score 0):

If you use JPA in a reactive context and you don't need to execute all your persistance operations inside a transaction, you can try to manually create a new transaction for each operation.

1 - Inject a PlatformTransactionManager

```
@Autowired
private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;
```

2 - Create a new TransactionTemplate (this could be done in constructor)

```
this.transactionTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager);
```

3 - Execute your persistent calls inside a call to `transactionTemplate.execute` :

```
personFlux.subscribe(person -> 
  transactionTemplate.execute(transactionStatus -> {
            CNPerson cnPerson = syncMgr.convertObject(person, CNPerson.class);
            cnPerson.setObiektLoid(obiekt.getLoid());
            em.persist(cnPerson);
            count.getAndIncrement();
});
```

Note that this will create a new transaction for each call to `em.persist`.